# How to pass arguments to already loaded tensorflow graph ( in memory )

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, object-detection

I have an object detection model trained using ssd-mobilenet architecture. I am driving inference in real time from this model  using my webcam. The output is a bounding box overlayed on the image from the webcam.

I am accessing my web cam as follows:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

Function to run inference in real-time on video feed:

```
with detection_graph.as_default():
  with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
    while True:
      ret, image_np = cap.read()
      # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
      image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
      image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
      # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected.
      boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
      # Each score represent how level of confidence for each of the objects.
      # Score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
      scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
      classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
      num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
      # Actual detection.
      (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
          [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
          feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
      # Visualization of the results of a detection.
      vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np,
          np.squeeze(boxes),
          np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
          np.squeeze(scores),
          category_index,
          use_normalized_coordinates=True,
          line_thickness=8)

      #print(boxes)


      for i, box in enumerate(np.squeeze(boxes)):
          if(np.squeeze(scores)[i] > 0.98):
              print("ymin={}, xmin={}, ymax={}, xmax{}".format(box[0]*height,box[1]*width,box[2]*height,box[3]*width))
      break

      cv2.imshow('object detection', cv2.resize(image_np, (300,300)))
      if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

The moment object is detected my terminal shows its normalised coordinates.

This is perfect for a video feed because:

- The model is already loaded in memory
- whenever new object comes in front of webcam the loaded model predicts that object and outputs its coordinates

I want the same functionality for image i.e. I want:

- The model already loaded in memory
- whenever new argument comes mentioning the image location, the loaded model predicts that object and outputs its coordinates.

How should I do that by modifying above code? I do not want a separate server to perform this task (as mentioned in tensorflow serving).

How do I do it locally on my machine ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to feed images stored in a particular directory to your model and get the predictions out?

Comment: What I want is the model will stay loaded in RAM and the moment I give it a command line argument with image path it will give me inference quickly, without reloading the entire model

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of `os.listdir()` command to list all the files in a given directory and then follow the same pipeline.

```
import os
import cv2
path = "./path/to/image/folder"
images = os.listdir(path)

with detection_graph.as_default():
  with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
    for image in images:
      image_path = os.path.join(path, image)
      image_np = cv2.imread(image_path)
      # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
      image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
      image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
      # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected.
      boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
      # Each score represent how level of confidence for each of the objects.
      # Score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
      scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
      classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
      num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
      # Actual detection.
      (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
          [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
          feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
      # Visualization of the results of a detection.
      vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np,
          np.squeeze(boxes),
          np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
          np.squeeze(scores),
          category_index,
          use_normalized_coordinates=True,
          line_thickness=8)

      #print(boxes)


      for i, box in enumerate(np.squeeze(boxes)):
          if(np.squeeze(scores)[i] > 0.98):
              print("ymin={}, xmin={}, ymax={}, xmax{}".format(box[0]*height,box[1]*width,box[2]*height,box[3]*width))
      break

      cv2.imshow('object detection', cv2.resize(image_np, (300,300)))
      if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Comment: No, this does not help. I think this is similar to googles open source example for tensorflow object detection (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb). What I want is the model will stay loaded in RAM and the moment I give it a command line argument with image path it will give me inference quickly, without reloading the entire model